# Integrate $\int_2^5 \dfrac{1}{1+\sqrt{x-1}}\, \mathrm{d}x $ using substitution with a fraction

Tags: integration

Im doing this question currently

$$\int_2^5 \dfrac{1}{1+\sqrt{x-1}}\, \mathrm{d}x $$

and I set $u = x-1$ to get $\tfrac{\mathrm{d}u}{\mathrm{d}x} =1$ so $du =dx$.

I then write it out as $$\frac{1}{1+\sqrt{u}}\,\mathrm{d}u$$

But then I hit a brick wall and I'm not sure how to further progress. I know I need to replace the $u$ but I'm not sure about anything else

Comment: Sub again: $t=1+\sqrt u$.

Comment: with $ u=x-1$, the bounds become $2-1=1$ and $5-1=4$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A single substitution will suffice:  $$u = 1 + \sqrt{x-1}$$ implies $$x = (u-1)^2 + 1 = u^2 - 2u + 2, \\ dx = 2u - 2 \, du.$$  Hence $$\int_{x=2}^5 \frac{dx}{1 + \sqrt{x-1}} = \int_{u=2}^3 \frac{2u-2}{u} \, du =2 \int_{u=2}^3 1 - \frac{1}{u} \ du = 2 \left[u - \log u \right]_{u=2}^3 = 2(1 + \log \tfrac{2}{3}).$$

Comment: thanks so much I get it now!

Answer (score 1):

**hint**

To eliminate the square root, you can put

$$\sqrt{u}=t \text{ or } u=t^2\text{ and } du=2tdt$$

the integral becomes

$$\int_1^4\frac{du}{1+\sqrt{u}}=\int_1^2\frac{2tdt}{1+t}$$

$$=2\int_1^2\frac{t+1-1}{t+1}dt$$

Answer (score 1):

With $u=x-1$

\begin{align}
 \int \dfrac{dx}{1+\sqrt{x-1}}=
&\int \dfrac{du}{1+\sqrt{u}}
=\int \frac{ 1+\sqrt{u}-1}{1+\sqrt{u}} \frac{du}{\sqrt{u}}\\
= &\>2\int \left(1-\frac1{1+\sqrt{u}}\right)d(\sqrt{u})
= 2\sqrt{u}-2\ln(1+\sqrt{u})
\end{align}